# Question on Quantum Harmonic Oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

My textbook claims that the uncertainty in position of the particle in a quantum harmonic oscillator is $\frac{A}{\sqrt{2}}$ and the uncertainty in the particle momentum is $\frac{p}{\sqrt{2}}$ whereby $A$ is the amplitude and $p$ is the momentum. It doesn't give an explanation for it. Can anyone explain to me why is this so?

Comment: Which textbook and which page?

Comment: It is University Physics by Young and Freedman, my first undergraduate modern physics course

Answer (score 4):

1.Uncertainty in position and in momentum

If you've taken a class of statistics, you should recall that for some variable $y$,
\begin{align} \sigma_y^2 = \sum (y_i-\bar y_i)^2 = \sum y_i^2 - \left(\sum y_i\right)^2  = \langle y^2\rangle - \langle y\rangle^2. 
\end{align}

Now, the expectation value of the position of the harmonic oscillator should be at the center (think about it classically, where would the average position of the object oscillating be? At its equilibrium position). Similarly, the expectation value of the position is at $p=0$, since its velocity changes from positive to negative in a symmetric manner. So,
\begin{align}
\sigma_x = \sqrt{\langle x^2\rangle},\qquad \sigma_p=\sqrt{\langle p^2\rangle}
\end{align}

2.Semi-classical approach. If you accept that the quantum harmonic oscillator behaves like a classical harmonic oscillator, that is $x(t) = A\sin(\omega t)$, where $A$ is the amplitude, then the expectation value of $\langle x^2\rangle$ can be computed via the above formula, but changing the discrete sum to an integral:
\begin{align*}
\langle x^2\rangle = \int_0^T A^2 \sin^2(\omega t)dt = \frac{A^2}{2}
\end{align*} where the period $T = 2\pi/\omega$. Similarly for the momentum, which if you take the classical approach, $p=mv = mdx/dt = mA\omega\cos(\omega t)$. Then, $m\omega A = |p|$, the amplitude of the momentum. I've used the absolute value signs to distinguish it from the momentum, which is really a vector. Then,
\begin{align*}
\langle p^2\rangle = \int_0^T m^2\omega^2 A^2 \cos^2(\omega t)dt = \frac{|p|^2}{2}
\end{align*}
Now, taking the square roots you get the answer you want.

The actual quantum mechanical explanation is somewhat similar, but the thing is that it comes from the usage of the Virial theorem, as well as the usage of quantum raising and lowering operators.